# Will the compiler inline the codes if the codes involving thread manipulations?

Tags: c++, multithreading, inline

I want to figure out the behavior of C++ compilers when a function involving thread manipulations and marked as inline.

For instance, this is a member method of a class. :

```
  inline Vec3 Pos() {
    unique_lock lock(mutex_);
    return pos_;
  }
```

If it's called by some client codes, will the compiler inline the codes (i.e. unroll the codes)? If it does, what is the unrolled version? Unscoped or scoped?

Answer (score 0):

In machine code there is no somthing like "scope". "scope" is language concept, which defines lifetime of variables.

Now in C/C++ there is "AS IF rule", meaning that compiler has right to do any transformation of code as long as all its visible outcomes remains unchanged. So effects of "scope" must remain unchanged.

In the past `inline` keyword meant "ensure this code is inserted to caller code". Nowadays it means "do not report an error, if you will find redefinition of this function". Compiler may insert this function code into callers code, but it doesn't have to.